# PayPal standard recurring payments fail with "Access Denied"

Tags: paypal, recurring-contributions

CiviCRM version 5.30.0, Wordpress 5.5.1, PHP 7.2.34

Single payments passed to PayPal proceed fine, but recurring payments are blocked by PayPal, reporting "Access Denied.

You don't have permission to access "/subscriptions?business=info [...]

PayPal technical support claims "Since your query parameter strings was passed with the special characters like "/wordpress/civicrm/?Dcivicrm%252F" which causing the access denied issues. "

We are using the standard CiviContribute resources with no special templates or other items.

Has anyone else hit this brick wall?  How did you manage to resolve it?

Incidentally, we were able to create new recurring contributions until about 2 weeks ago with no system changes around the time of the failure.

Comment: CiviCRM 5.30.0 WP 5.5.1 PHP 7.4.10. I can also make single CiviContribute PayPal payments but not recurring payments. We are also using standard CiviContribute resources. I turned off recurring payments, looking forward to seeing if anyone has ideas about how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal appears to have resolved whatever firewall blockage was preventing access to their subscription services.  We are again able to set up recurring contributions without having changed anything within our site configuration.